# Talend Varying Input Columns

Tags: talend

I've written a program that draws polygons on a map and returns the points of the polygon, this would then need to get put into a database. I am using the free version of Talend, you see my problem is **with polygons you could have as many points as you could click,** in talend you need to define a schema. **I need a way to input as many points as I have in my database in a child table.** I've read about dynamic schemas but it hasnt really answered my question. Thanks in advance for the help everyone.

Comment: You can use the schema key value, can you please provide more specefic description ?

Comment: I made a work around by writing a script in java that took all my points and put them in one column, my problem was that I was unsure how many columns I would have, if I had 400 points to a shape I'd have 400+ columns for that singular line, the next line could have a triangle as its shape and would have 3 points having very few columns.

Comment: This is the problem of any sql data base, it has a schema that hav to be respected, why not to use a schemaless data base like MongoDB ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have dynamic schema with the paid version I know

[See here](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=190513179&focusedCommentId=269544791&_ga=1.89731218.881072104.1483435100#comment-269544791)

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature like dynamic schema in Talend Open Studio.
But a licensed Talend Data fabric has an option for dynamic schema.

Below is the screenshot for reading a csv file without knowing the schema, we can do the same for databases.
Here is an example of 
 [dynamic schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtvWW.jpg)